# str() doesn't work in the body of my function

Tags: python, type-conversion

I am trying to write a simple function where I need to concatenate a string and an integer converted into a string. My code is as follows:

```
def bonus_time(salary, bonus):
    total_Salary = 0

    if bonus == True:
        total_Salary = salary * 10
    else:
        total_Salary = salary

    print(total_Salary)    
    str(total_Salary)        
    return "$" + total_Salary

print(bonus_time(1000, True))
```

The error I get is that python cannot concatenate string and int, even though I am using `str()` to convert the int to a string.

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: str(total_Salary) creates a string, from total_salary but nothing is assigned to it.  This does not change total_salary which is a number.

Comment: BTW, `if bonus == True` should be written `if bonus` per [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) under "Don't compare boolean values to True or False using ==."

Comment: You would have to do `total_Salary = str(total_Salary)` because what you have right now turns it into a string but doesn't save it anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

You do not reassign the converted value. Simply change your return statement to

```
return "$" + str(total_Salary)
```

and omit the previous call to str(). Additionally, `total_Salary = 0` has no influence as you're changing the variable afterwards.

---

Summing up, you could write:

```
def bonus_time(salary, bonus):
    if bonus:
        total_Salary = salary * 10
    else:
        total_Salary = salary

    print(total_Salary)

    return "$" + str(total_Salary)
```

Or - even shorter, using the ternary operator:

```
def bonus_time(salary, bonus):
    total_Salary = salary * 10 if bonus else salary
    return "${}".format(total_Salary)
```

I'd argue though that your first if/else expression is more readable and should be used instead.

Answer (score 2):

replace :

```
str(total_Salary)

return "$" + total_Salary
```

with

```
return "$" + str(total_Salary)
```